# AWS amazon SES stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sendmail

I am not able to send the mail from aws.amazon SES since from Monday (30-10-2012) previously it is working fine suddenly it stopped working. I got following is the errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: User Warning

Message: SimpleEmailService::getSendQuota(): Sender - RequestExpired: Request timestamp: Wed, 31 Oct 2012 11:50:32 UTC expired. It must be within 300 secs/ of server time. Request Id: e472fb5a-2351-11e2-8183-8138c6c456cf

Filename: libraries/ses.php

Line Number: 363
```

But this same code working with fine in another server What may be the issue Please help,I could not find solution for this.

Comment: As a quick suggestion, check the SES time by making an HTTP request to SES (e.g. `wget -S  "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"`), and compare to your server's time. Update the server's time (or use NTP if you aren't already) and see if the problem resolves itself.

Comment: Britain (and probably other countries) switched over to winter time at the same day your error started happening and the error says that the time is more than 300 seconds wrong.  I would vote for that being the root cause.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this?  I use SES and am curious in case I ever ran into the same.